# crystal formula explanation

Tags: crystal-reports, report

Can anyone explain this formula?

```
shared numbervar amount121 ;

if  {hdr.postdate} <= DateAdd("d", - (181+{@PatermDays}), {@postto})
and ({dtl.cleardate} = cdate('01/01/1900') or {dtl.cleardate} > {@postto})then 
(    if not isnull({#RInvAmount}) and not isnull({#RPaymentAmount}) and {#RInvAmount} >0 then
       ( amount121 := amount121 + ({#RInvAmount}-{#RPaymentAmount});
        {#RInvAmount}-{#RPaymentAmount};)
    else if not isnull({#RInvAmount})and {#RInvAmount} >0 then
        (amount121 := amount121 + {#RInvAmount};
        {#RInvAmount};)
    else 
    0

)
```

patterm days, post to  , #Rinvamount, #RPaymentAmount is another formulas which is linked in formula

Comment: where are you finding difficult to understand.. its just a if else

Comment: whole.. in first line what is "d" and cdate in 2nd line etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok will try to explain to the extent possible: check the text after **//**

```
shared numbervar amount121 ; //Varible decleration with shared scope

if  {hdr.postdate} <= DateAdd("d", - (181+{@PatermDays}), {@postto})     //"d" deleting those many number of days and coverting resultant to datetime

and ({dtl.cleardate} = cdate('01/01/1900') or {dtl.cleardate} > {@postto})then     //Cdate converting string to date used for comparing the date field

(    if not isnull({#RInvAmount}) and not isnull({#RPaymentAmount}) and {#RInvAmount} >0 then     //Comparing the running totals that are not null

       ( amount121 := amount121 + ({#RInvAmount}-{#RPaymentAmount});     //subtracting and storing values in variable

        {#RInvAmount}-{#RPaymentAmount};)     //Not sure what is this doing here

    else if not isnull({#RInvAmount})and {#RInvAmount} >0 then     //If fails then using other running totals in else if

        (amount121 := amount121 + {#RInvAmount};     //Again storing values in else if

        {#RInvAmount};)     //Not sure what is this doing here

    else      //if and else if fails then control comes to this part
    0 

)
```